# Angular signal issue State management

Tags: angular, signals, ngrx

**● TestComponent › should create

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userIds')
  2 | import { TestReducers } from '../reducers';
  3 |
> 4 | export const getuserIds = createSelector(TestReducers.TestFeatureSelector, state => state.userIds);**
    |                                                                                                       ^
```

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let store: MockStore<State>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent], // Replace with the actual declarations used in TestComponent.
            providers: [
                provideMockStore({
                    initialState: {
                        userIds: '1234'
                    },
                }),
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        store = TestBed.inject(MockStore<State>);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The below is my selector using from component
userId = this.store.selectSignal(getUserIds);

The below is my selector
export const getUserIds = createSelector(TestReducers.TestFeatureSelector, state => state.userIds);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the store is not instantiated correctly, specifically that the initial doesn't have the correct shape.

```
  provideMockStore({
                    initialState: {
                        userIds: '1234'
                    },
                }),
```

Creates a store with just `userIds` as state property, the state will look as :

```
{
  userIds: '1234'
}
```

While the selector expects a feature state:

```
export const getuserIds = createSelector(TestReducers.TestFeatureSelector, state => state.userIds);
```

This means that you should update the initial state to match the expected state:

```
  provideMockStore({
                    initialState: {
                        useYourFeatureNameHere: {
                           userIds: '1234'
                        }
                    },
                }),
```

Comment: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
showing the below error at 
[TestReducers.TestFeatureSelector]

Comment: My bad, that should be your feature name (the property name within the state)